# c++ random numbers, evenly distributed

Tags: c++, random, numbers

I need to generate random numbers between two values in c++, which can be generated like that(in a range 1 to 6)
:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
 srand(time(NULL));

for (int j = 0; j < 6 ; j++) {
    randomNumber = rand() % 6 + 1;
    cout << randomNumber;

return 0;
}
```

But I also need to ensure that it generates at least once each number in the range, for example: range [1,6], you must generate at least once the 1,2,3,4,5 and 6.

And there is another thing, the numbers generated, must be evenly distributed, like if want generate 20 iterations in range of[1,6], each number(1,2,3,4,5,6) should have approximately the same quantity generated at 20 iterations. Example: 1,3,5,2,4,6,2,4,6,1,3,5,6,5,4,3,5,2,1.... and not like this: 1,3,5,6,6,6,2,6,4,4,4,4,4,4...

If anyone knows how to solve this, I'll be very grateful to you.
Thanks!!!

Comment: Would it be valid for you to add all numbers to container, and then grab numbers from the container, if you run out just shuffle it again? theres also another math thing to do this but i cant remember the name of it

Comment: I think you could use a vector of int, add all the numbers you want as output, then shuffle the elements in the vector a finally retrieve them from the end

Comment: It's NOT random if you want to guarantee all number will shows up.

Comment: Please read tag descriptions before adding them, the [tag:generate] tag is about a framework named Generate and is not relevant to this question.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4fadd1893f7893d
This kind of does what you want from what I can tell but its not truly random.

Comment: Oh I didn't think about that, put the values in a vector and then shuffle them, well I'm gonna search a little more about that, thanks.

Comment: People can be sticklers for language: it would appear that you want your non-random number range delivered to you in random order?

Comment: exactly @Dúthomhas

Comment: size_t iter_count = 23; //the size_t it's just for computacional improvement right, we could use int?

Comment: @Borgleader can you explain me this: size_t shuffle_count = (iter_count + s.size() - 1) / s.size();

Answer (score 2):

This is where the C++ Standard Library comes to the rescue. Typed off the top of my head:

```
#include <random>

int get_rand_in_1_6()
{
  static std::random_device rnd;
  return std::uniform_int_distribution <int> ( rnd )( 1, 6 );
}
```

The result will be uniformly-distributed.

(You may not get one of each in the first six iterations, though. Being *uniformly distributed* does not guarantee any specific values in any specific sub-interval, only that the number is just as likely as any other to appear. Given enough iterations, you will see that.)

[edit 2]: IDR the exact mathematical formula for minimum number of iterations to guarantee that you see each number at least once — I am wildly guessing around 15 for the minimum number of pulls to guarantee that.

Comment: thanks @Dúthomhas

Comment: There is no *guarantee* for a minimum number of pulls which will contain all outcomes, the probability of there being at least one value you haven't seen is mathematically non-zero for all sample sizes. However, it very rapidly becomes so close to zero that nobody would care. Kind of like the probability of all the air molecules in a room simultaneously rushing to one corner - theoretically it could happen, but nobody I know is concerned about asphyxiating from this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, `std::shuffle` might help you:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
int numbers[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

for (int j = 0; j < 20 ; j++) {
    if (j % 6 == 0) { std::shuffle(numbers, numbers + 6, gen); }
    std::cout << numbers[j % 6];
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03f38af556f2d1c2)

You have then sequence of random permutations.